# Adding Detail Tables (GridTableView) to Persistence Manager

Tags: asp.net, telerik, persistence, radgrid

I am unable to discover how you can enable Persistence Framework Manager to check for and serialize the column data (display/order/ect) inside of a Detail Table.  I have the Detail Table's parent RadGrid properly saving column display/order, but it is not automatically serializing the child GridViewTable. According to http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/persistence-framework-supported-controls.html, GridTableViews are supported by Persistence Framework.

Could anyone shed some light on how I may add this to my Persistence Manager? It does not seem that GridTableViewcan be assigned an ID from the ASPX page, thus, I have not been able to add it to my manager in the way in which I did my RadGrid.

Thank you,

AlexK

**UPDATE:**
I attempted to add the Detail Table via the code behind by adding the following on the Page_Init event...

```
PersistenceManager.PersistenceSettings.AddSetting(ParentRadGrid.MasterTableView.DetailTables(0))
```

This threw a `PersistenceFrameworkException` with the details stating 
`The control of Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView could not be persisted. Please review the online documetation for the supported controls.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the **MasterTableView** is supported, I have asked, DetailTables are not. The documentation is to be fixed :)